# Mv several file to directory with same basename

Tags: bash, directory, mv

I have several files with different extensions and directories with the same basename, like this example.

```
FileA.txt
FileA.html
FileA.directory/

FileB.txt
FileB.html
FileB.directory/

FileC.txt
FileC.html
FileC.directory/
```

And i would like to create a for-loop for which i can move all files to their corresponding directory based on their basename. Resulting in the following

```
FileA.directory/FileA.txt
FileA.directory/FileA.html

FileB.directory/FileB.txt
FileB.directory/FileB.html

FileC.directory/FileC.txt
FileC.directory/FileC.html
```

I've tried to find several suggestion which are kind of similar to my problem on this page, like this example. But i can't find a completely similar question.

```
for dir in .*/
do
    for f in "$dir"*
    do
        base=${f#$dir}
        mv "$base.*" "$dir"
    done
done
```

However I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we know that all files have the filename suffixes `.html` or `.txt` and that all directories have the suffix `.directory`, you can use:

```
for i in *.txt *.html
 do
  mv "$i" "${i%%.*}.directory/$i"
 done
```

Run this in same directory where you are having files.
It will remove trailing .txt and .html from file names and then will move files to destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names of the files and directories follow the same naming convention in that they share some common grouping prefix followed by a dot, and assuming we don't know the filename suffixes of files or directories:

```
topdir=.

for dirname in "$topdir"/*/; do
    prefix=$( basename "$dirname" )  # $topdir/FileC.directory/ --> FileC.directory
    prefix=${prefix%%.*}             # FileC.directory          --> FileC

    for filename in "$topdir/$prefix".*; do
        if [ ! -d "$filename" ]; then
            mv -i "$filename" "$dirname"
        fi
    done
done
```

The outer loop iterates over all directories in the directory `$topdir` (here set to `.`, the current directory).  The `$prefix` will be the base name of the directory name, with the bit after the first dot removed.

Once the prefix has been computed, non-directories (files) in the same `$topdir` directory that share the same prefix are moved to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
dirs=$(ls | grep ".d")
for d in $dirs
do
    filename=$(echo $d | awk -F"." '{print $1}')
    ls | grep  -P "$filename.(?!(d))" | xargs -I{} mv '{}' '$d'
done
```

Maybe too verbose, but it works

Comment: Note that `.d` also matches strings like `bad` since `.` matches any character.

Comment: You should escape it "\."

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv It's not enough. That may still match `FileA.draft.txt`, even though the given list in the question does not contain such a filename.

Comment: Related: [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what do to instead)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)